# Shifting elements in C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of integers with 35 slots. I want to insert a value and each time a new value is inserted, I want the first value to remain the tail and the new value to become the head. I cannot use linked lists or queues, I have to use a void function. I cannot figure out an algorithm, but everything I have thought of has included a for loop, I just don't know how to implement it properly.

**ArrayList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
using namespace std;

ArrayList::ArrayList() {
    capacity = 8;
    length = 0;
    array = new int[capacity];
}

ArrayList::ArrayList(const ArrayList& other) {
    length = other.length;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    array = new int[other.capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i <= capacity; i++)
        array[i] = other.array[i];
}

void ArrayList::add(int item) {
    if (length <= capacity) {
        changeCapacityTo(2 * capacity);
    }
    length++;
    array[length++] = item;
}

void ArrayList::add(int index, int item) {
    while (index > capacity || length == capacity) {
        capacity *= 2;
    }

    if (length != 0 && length < index) {
        length = index;
    }

    int temp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        array[index] = item;
        temp = array[index];
        array[index + 1] = temp;
    }
    length++;
}

int ArrayList::get(int index) const {
    return array[index];
}

void ArrayList::changeCapacityTo(int newCapacity) {
    int *newArray = new int[newCapacity];
    int numItemsToCopy = length < newCapacity ? length : newCapacity;
    for (int i = 0; i < numItemsToCopy; i++)
    newArray[i] = array[i];
    delete[] array;
    array = newArray;
}
```

**testArrayList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayList.h"
using namespace std;

void verifyArrayList(ArrayList arrayList) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      int item;
      int itemToAdd = 2 * i;
      if((item = arrayList.get(i)) != itemToAdd)
         cout << "OOPS - Error at index " << i << ": " << item << " should be "
                     << itemToAdd << endl;
   }

}
void printArrayList(ArrayList arrayList) {
   for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.getLength(); ++i) {
      int item = arrayList.get(i);
      cout << i << ":" << item << endl;
   }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   ArrayList arrayList;

   const int highIndex = 35;
   for(int i = highIndex; i > 0; --i) {
      int itemToAdd = 2 * i;
      arrayList.add(1, itemToAdd);

      //cout << "VALUE OF itemToAdd: " << itemToAdd << endl;
      //cout << endl;
   }
   arrayList.add(99);
   printArrayList(arrayList);
   cout << "#items = " << arrayList.getLength() << endl;
   cout << "capacity = " << arrayList.getCapacity() << endl;

   arrayList.add(2000, 9999);
   cout << "#items = " << arrayList.getLength() << endl;
   cout << "capacity = " << arrayList.getCapacity() << endl;
}
```

**ArrayList.h**

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H_
#define ARRAYLIST_H_
#include <iostream>

class ArrayList {
public:
   /*
    * Initialize list with a capacity of 8
    */
   ArrayList();

   /*
    * Copy constructor
    */
   ArrayList(const ArrayList& other);
   virtual ~ArrayList() {
      std::cout << "Destructing ArrayList at " << array << std::endl;
      delete [] array;
      array = NULL;
   }

   /*
    * Add item to end of list
    * @param item item to add to list
    */
   void add(int item);

   /*
    * Adds item to list, at index, shifting items as necessary and increasing
    * capacity of list as necessary. If capacity must increase, it must always
    * be a power of 2. Note that if index is beyond capacity, capacity must be
    * increased to allow adding the item at that index. Also, length should
    * reflect the HIGHEST index (plus one, naturally) at which an item is
    * stored, even if lower-indexed slots contain undefined values.
    *
    * @param item item to add to list
    */
   void add(int index, int item);

   /*
    * Return item at index. For now, we assume index is legal.
    * Later we will throw an exception when index is illegal.
    * @param index index of item to return
    * @return item at index
    */
   int get(int index) const;

   /*
    * Return capacity
    * @return capacity
    */
   int getCapacity() const {
      return capacity;
   }

   /*
    * Return current length
    * @return current length
    */
   int getLength() const {
      return length;
   }

private:
   int *array;
   int length;
   int capacity;
   /*
    * Change capacity to that specified by newCapacity.
    * @param newCapacity the new capacity
    */
   void changeCapacityTo(int newCapacity);
};

#endif /* ARRAYLIST_H_ */
```

Here's what the output should look like:
[CORRECT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FujBk.png)

Here's what my output looks like:
[MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90ets.png)

**NEW FUNCTION**

I'm attempting to copy the first 35 values of `array` in reverse, assign them to `reverseArray`, and then assign the reversed order back to array. The following code is not working doing what I expect.

```
void ArrayList::add(int index, int item) {
while (index > capacity || length == capacity) {
    capacity *= 2;
}

if (length != 0 && length < index) {
    length = index;
}

int temp;
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    array[index] = item;
    temp = array[index];
    array[index + 1] = temp;

}
length++;
if(length > 35) {
    int reverseArray[35];
    reverse_copy(array, array + 35, reverseArray);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 35; i++) {
        array[i] = reverseArray[i];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you use std::swap?

Comment: insert a value where in the array?  what do you mean by head and tail when referring to an array?

Comment: Please edit your question, and include a [mcve] containing what you have coded to date, and include some sample input, the actual results, and the expected results.

Comment: Look up the following functions: `std::copy` and `memmove`.  These functions will help you "shift" elements in your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. initialize a pointer to the end of array.
2. foreach every new element, set it as the value which is pointed by current pointer, and reduce current pointer by 1.

If you use the void return function, you can pass new element value and current pointer as the parameter. And pay attention to check current pointer.